# parsing boolean operators in text search

Tags: php, parsing, search, text, boolean

I am looking to build some search functionality that would support boolean operators and convert the search string into a database query. for example the user could type an expression like

```
"(laptops OR tablets) NOT (Windows Or (Mac OS))"
```

and the intended result would include any laptop or tablet with an OS other than Windows or Mac

I am already tokenizing the keywords and just need to figure out how to parse the user query string

Any help in this regard would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  SO will not write your code, but could help debug it.

Comment: At the moment I am stumped on the approach - currently the application just does the vanilla "LIKE" query using each of the search terms and comparing it to the tokens. the current approach I am thinking of is to identify the first NOT in the string that's followed by an opening parenthesis and then identifying the boundary at the next closing parenthesis and then moving to the AND and finally the OR.... but I don't know if this is the best approach

Comment: Parse in in a sort of AST, using specific handlers for each token compile it into the query.

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to create a own language. The user types "your" language and you translate it to database query. Why not make the user type a database query directly?

Comment: You'll have to parse the input string for expressions. There are libraries which can help you with that. Take a look at Symfony Expression Language for example (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html).